# Extra blank page at the beginning of the document

Tags: errors

I am getting an extra page before the document if I add thanks in the footnote of the first page of the document, and if I remove it, the extra page is gone. My document begins as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\title
\author
\thanks
```

If I remove `\thanks`, the extra page disappears. I want to add thanks in the footnote. What should I do ?

Comment: Put it inside the author statement.

Answer (score 3):

In the LaTeX standard document classes like `article`, `book` or `report`, the command `\thanks` is not meant to be used as an independent command like `\author` or `\title`, but would be used inside the argument of one of these.

For example you would write

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \title{A thesis\thanks{A real one}}
  \author{John Doe\thanks{Husband of Jane Doe}}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

Comment: while it's true that `\thanks` is "dependent" for `article`, it is independent with `amsart` and perhaps other document classes.  the question wasn't specific about document class, so the class used should be stated specifically in your answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I wasn't aware some classes use this differently.